# Getting new answers on an old and popular question

Tags: discussion

Usually, the most basic questions on various topics exist in SO for a while, have tons of upvotes and tons of upvoted good and not so good answers. The things is that sometimes the initial question was asked so long ago, most (if not all) answers might be outdated. If I want to have a new look at the same topic, without getting my question closed as double, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could offer a bounty on the existing question, making it clear that you want a more up-to-date answer.

It is convenient if we have answers to the same question in one place. Even if some answers are outdated, some of us work with legacy systems and the answers may consequently still be of value to them.
That being said, if you encounter an answer that is out of date, adding a polite comment (and a more up-to-date answer if you have one) never hurts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, that makes sense. The more common situation however is not necessarily outdated answers in a sense that they are not correct anymore but in terms of new approach or new options.